# How can I place a String in brackets within my EXTRA_SUBJECT for email intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to put the `name.getText().toString()`in brackets after the `messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Submit Name For "`

So for example:

```
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Submit Name For " + name.getText().toString());
```

so that the output in the email subject would be `Submit Name For (Example)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add strings like this. It's simple :)

```
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Submit Name For " +"("+ name.getText().toString()+")");
```

Comment: That simple :-)  Thanks!! appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format()`

```
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.format("Submit Name For (%s)", name.getText().toString()));
```